# Optimization of a triangle fit within the dimensions of a rectangle.

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, optimization

Consider a rectangle $ABCD$ where $A$ is the bottom left corner, $D$ is the top left corner, $C$ is the top right corner and $B$ is the bottom right corner. $DC$ and $AB$ are both $11$ units long and $DA$ and $CB$ are both 7 units long. Now consider 2 more points, $F$ and $E$. $E$ lies on $BC$, $x$ units above $B$ and $F$ lies on $DC$, $2x$ units to the left of $C$. All these points are on the perimeter of the rectangle.

A triangle $AFE$ is then formed.

Find the value of $x$ which the area of the triangle will be the least.

I have tried different ways in terms of area of triangles etc. However I have made no progress. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get an expression for the area to be minimised?

Comment: No i haven't been able to figure out a suitable equation to minimise.

Comment: Consider subtracting from the area of the rectangle the three right triangles at the corners you do not want. You should get a quadratic expression, hitch is easy to minimise,by say completing the square.

Comment: I have done that and i got a cubic. $$A_{Triangle} = 77-\frac{1}{2}\left(2x^3-14x^2+3x-77\right)$$

Comment: That was found by adding all the triangles together: $$77=\frac{1}{2}(11-2x)+\frac{7-x}{2}(2x^2)+\frac{11x}{2}+A_{Triangle}$$

Comment: You may need to recheck that...

Comment: Ok will do, I'll comment it when finished if i've made any changes

Comment: I see where i've made the mistake, it should be $+\frac{7-x}{2}(2x)...$

Comment: I got a value for the area of the triangle $AFE$. $13.84$

Comment: Wait, I'm supposed to find $f'(A_{Triangle})$

Comment: @Brayden did you get your answer ?

Comment: Yes i did thankyou, it ended up being something along the lines of $x=2.75$ for minimum area of the triangle $AFE$.

Answer (score 2):

We can subtract the area of the other right triangles from the rectangle to get this area. We therefore want to maximize the sum of those values:

The areas of triangles $ABE$, $EBF$, and $FDA$ are $\frac{11x}{2}$, $7x-x^2$, and $\frac{77-14x}{2}$ respectively. (You can find these easily, since those are all right triangles)

The sum of those is $-x^2+\frac{11}{2}x+\frac{77}{2}$. Completing the square, we have:

$-(x-\frac{11}{4})^2+\frac{737}{16}$.

Therefore, the maximum area of the other triangles is $\frac{737}{16}$, making the minimum area of $\triangle AEF$:

$77-\frac{737}{16}=\frac{495}{16}$.

My arithmetic may be off, but this general strategy will work.